# Why does my std::function have no viable conversion?

Tags: c++, qt, std-function

My Compressor class has field `QMap<QString, std::function<DataList(Compressor&, DataList &)> &> *techniques;` and static method `static DataList & sndStep(DataList &l);`. Their type definitions:

```
typedef QPair<QPointF, QString> Data;
typedef QList<Data> DataList;
typedef QList<DataList> DataTable;
```

I'm trying to create a `QMap` which will contain the `QString` name of technique as Key and technique as Value.

At first, I tried to insert pair `("R0", sndStep)`{

```
Compressor::Compressor(const QString& s)
{
  std::function<DataList(Compressor&, Datalist&)> f =  
      [] (DataList & l) {
          return &Compressor::sndStep(DataList & l);
       };

  techniques->insert("R0", f);
}
```

But I got many errors. One of them is "no viable conversion":

```
compressor.cpp:8:53: error: no viable conversion from '(lambda at C:\Qt\Projects\ChartWithMenu\compressor.cpp:9:9)' to 'std::function<DataList (Compressor &, DataList &)>' (aka 'function<QList<QPair<QPointF, QString>> (Compressor &, QList<QPair<QPointF, QString>> &)>')
std_function.h:402:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from '(lambda at C:\Qt\Projects\ChartWithMenu\compressor.cpp:9:9)' to 'std::nullptr_t' (aka 'nullptr_t') for 1st argument
std_function.h:413:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from '(lambda at C:\Qt\Projects\ChartWithMenu\compressor.cpp:9:9)' to 'const std::function<QList<QPair<QPointF, QString>> (Compressor &, QList<QPair<QPointF, QString>> &)> &' for 1st argument
std_function.h:422:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from '(lambda at C:\Qt\Projects\ChartWithMenu\compressor.cpp:9:9)' to 'std::function<QList<QPair<QPointF, QString>> (Compressor &, QList<QPair<QPointF, QString>> &)> &&' for 1st argument
std_function.h:446:2: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Functor = (lambda at C:\Qt\Projects\ChartWithMenu\compressor.cpp:9:9), $1 = void]: no type named 'type' in 'std::result_of<(lambda at C:\Qt\Projects\ChartWithMenu\compressor.cpp:9:9) &(Compressor &, QList<QPair<QPointF, QString>> &)>'
compressor.cpp:9:9: note: candidate function
```

How can I fix this error?  Or maybe are there other ways to create a map of functions (not necessarily `std::function`)?

Comment: `DataList(Compressor&, Datalist&)` and the lambda signatures don't appear to match. And `&Compressor::sndStep(DataList & l);` doesn't look like legal code.

Comment: Why are you storing references to `std::function`? `f` is a local variable and you'll have a dangling reference as soon as `Compressor::Compressor` returns. You should store by value instead, e.g. `QMap<QString, std::function<DataList(Compressor&, DataList &)>>` (without the last `&`)

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are about to define `f` as a function taking two arguments (`Compressor&, Datalist&`) and returning `DataList`:

```
std::function<DataList(Compressor&, Datalist&)> f
```

but that's not the signature of the lambda:

```
    [] (DataList & l) {
        return &Compressor::sndStep(DataList & l);
    };
```

which only takes one argument (`DataList&`) and returns something not known from the code snippet you've shown.

Comment: There is no way that lambda compiles...right?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili No, not that I can see anyway. Perhaps with some exotic macro help :-)